# Process class not working in swift 3

Tags: swift, process, swift3, nstask

For some reason the **Process** class is not registering as apart of the **Foundation** import even though it is clearly stated [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/process) in the Apple Swift language API Library that the **Process** class is a part of **Foundation**.

For example:

```
import Foundation

let task = Process()
```

throws the error:

> use of unresolved identifier Process

I have tried using NSTask, which is what the Process class used to be called but that does not work either.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
import Foundation

var str = "let str = \"Hello\"\nprintln(\"\\(str) world\")\n"

let task = Process()

task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/swift"

let outpipe = Pipe()
let inpipe = Pipe()
inpipe.fileHandleForWriting.write(str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
task.standardInput = inpipe
task.standardOutput = outpipe
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
task.standardInput = Pipe()

let data = outpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
```

which creates the “str” constant from text. And yes I know that this is forbidden by Apple but it is not for an app on the App Store.

So basically I need to know what NSTask has been changed to in swift 3.0

I am using the latest version of Xcode (8.1) and the latest version of Swift (3.0). Please help!

Comment: Is your app for iOS or macOS? `Process` is only available for macOS, not iOS.

Comment: Oooohhhhh. Yes it is iOS. So what would you use instead since NSTask is no longer available?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have not provided any information about what you want to do.

Comment: I have edited my question to show what I really want to accomplish @rmaddy

Comment: iOS doesn't allow you to launch other processes. Apple doesn't allow apps to run code.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your help anyway!